# Django Migration Error 'TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found' on mysql-connector-python cursor_cent.py file

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-migration, django-migrations

I'm using mysql-connector to handle mysql requests in a Django project. Problem is I'm setting up a simple  project with "django-admin startproject project ." and when I try to do a simple manage.py migrate, this is my output.

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
aqui <mysql.connector.cursor_cext._ParamSubstitutor object at 0x7f408ae1ec10> b'SELECT engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = %s'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 68, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 348, in create_model
    self.deferred_sql.extend(self._model_indexes_sql(model))
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1087, in _model_indexes_sql
    output.extend(self._field_indexes_sql(model, field))
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1106, in _field_indexes_sql
    if self._field_should_be_indexed(model, field):
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 111, in _field_should_be_indexed
    storage = self.connection.introspection.get_storage_engine(
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/introspection.py", line 270, in get_storage_engine
    cursor.execute(
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 149, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, new_args)
  File "/home/thejhoule/anon/anonproj/end/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 265, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

I have the settings already properly configured as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'XXXXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXX',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True
        }
    }
}
```

and the dbname database properly created via mysql shell. I also notice that two tables are created on this db when I run "python manage.py migrate" 2 times (the first time I run it, the above error happens but no tables are created on my db).

I tried messing with code near `stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)`, even tried to input `stmt.decode('utf-8')`. It then raises a different error at the same point

```
tmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt.decode('utf-8'))
TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and am doing all of this in a python venv, with django and mysql-connector-python installed via pip.

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: have you solved the issue ?

Comment: No, i managed to work with mysqlclient though... But this seems broken

Comment: Just encountered this with mysql-connector as well - may be a bug there.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug with `mysql-connector-python==8.0.27` and can be avoided by rolling back one version:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python<=8.0.26
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have created and defined the two mandatory files views.py and urls.py for your app?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What makes you think this error has anything to do with missing views or URLs? Please make sure your answers actually address the question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Yes, it is done