# how to fix typeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-models

i'm trying to create an object in database with django. my configuration is below.

```
'nucoin' : {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': "db_name",
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': 'db_host',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'SSL': True,
    },
```

and i'm getting the following trackback..

```
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/ahmed/bitbucket/notification_platform_sdk/backend/projects/managers.py", line 23, in create
    project.save(using="nucoin")
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 149, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, new_args)
  File "/home/ahmed/gitclones/clone-beru/web_push/backend/envNotifer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 263, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

if you need more detail. tell me in comment i'll update my question according to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Migration Error 'TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found' on mysql-connector-python cursor\_cent.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900463/django-migration-error-typeerror-sequence-item-1-expected-a-bytes-like-object)

Comment: No answer marked there.

Comment: Did you try `pip install mysql-connector-python<=8.0.26
`

Comment: yeah it worked. can you explain why 8.0.27 didn't worked ?

Comment: Can you answer it. So i can approve your answer for rest of peoples

Comment: I have no idea, just did a quick look in SO. There is no answer to approve, I just took it from the gut answered it in the post I paste, cheers