# How to switch from sqlite to mysql database in django?

Tags: python, django

I deployed my Django project on Cpanel, now when I want to change the default database:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
}
```

}

to the MySQL database (the ENGINE of the database is `'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',` because i'm not be able to install mysqlclient), it didn't migrate and gave me this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

After this error, the database created 2 tables named django_content_type and django_migrations.

but when I'm using the default database of Django it works and migrates everything

Comment: According to the Django documentation, the appropriate setting for ENGINE for MySQL is `'django.db.backends.mysql'`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: Your right but im not able to install mysqlclient in my host, and i prefer to install a connector for that

Comment: Depending on what version you are using, this might be relevant - with a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70010769/8432513